# Login with one button

Tags: javascript, firefox, authentication, popup

I have a [login](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~std10093/login.php) page, which will open the actual page (another url), if the password is correct.

Here is the script I run:

```
<script>
 var dataGlobal;
 $('#in1').click(function(){
    var reply = prompt("Password", "");
    if(!reply) return; // user pressed cancel
    $.post('/~std10093/scheduler_pass.php', {elements: reply}, function(data) {
      if(data != "not")
        alert("Password ok, press the second button to enter scheduler");
      else
        alert("prits");
      dataGlobal = data;
    });
 });
 $('#in2').click(function(){
    window.open(dataGlobal);
 });
</script>
```

Now the user has to click the first button, give the password and then click the other button which will open the new url. I want to do this only with one button, is it possible?

If I modify the code above and move `window.open(dataGlobal);` into the body of the `if(data != "not")` (which is the body that we will go into if the password is correct), firefox will prevent the new page from loading, since it prevents pop-up windows.

[image]

In the image above, one can see also the two buttons I was referring to previously.

---

Ideally I would like to replace `window.open()` with something that will not trigger the prevention of a pop-up window.

---

EDIT

I want to have another url for the actual page. The actual page is the scheduler from [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%B9/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%AF-results/), which is public, thus the url of the login is public too. However, I want the url for the scheduler to be private, so that people I trust can access it without login.

Comment: Instead of linking to another page you could show/hide a div and put your content there.

Comment: @brso05 that's probably not very secure unless maybe you appended contents to the div

Comment: @SimonStaton how so? How is it any less secure then another page?

Comment: @brso05 if you appended the contents should be okay, if you simply put secure content in a div and hide/show then you can simply edit source

Comment: @SimonStaton yes that is correct he should be using `ajax` or something to populate the div after successful login.

Comment: @brso05 I had thought of that too. I edited.

Comment: Must it open in another window/tab? Can it just replace the login window?

Comment: Could you not use `window.location.href = dataGlobal` ?

Comment: In that case, no, you need to open the second window on a user event. Otherwise, it's effectively a popup.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the answer works as expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a popup why not just use the current window?

In which case change to:

```
 $('#in2').click(function(){
    window.location.href = dataGlobal;
 });
```

**Edit:- can move to callback:**

```
<script>
 var dataGlobal;
 $('#in1').click(function(){
    var reply = prompt("Password", "");
    if(!reply) return; // user pressed cancel
    $.post('/~std10093/scheduler_pass.php', {elements: reply}, function(data) {
      if(data != "not")
        window.location.href = data;
      else
        alert("prits");
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the issue at all. `window.open` will work in this case. He's trying to do this in the AJAX callback.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara window.open() will create a new browser window (blocked by firefox) where as window.location.href will use the current window? - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp "The open() method opens a new browser window."

Comment: Simon is right @AlexanderO'Mara, just checked it. Again a firefox claimed that a pop-up with `open()`.

Comment: @SimonStaton Yes, but you replaced `window.open` in the click-to-open button, not the login button. `window.open` is permitted in a click handler, and should not trip popup blockers.

Comment: Then you can move it into the callback, my answer was relating to the  firefox popup issue which can be blocked by firefox popup blocker as it is.... a popup